# How to SUM the values in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Date]
      ,[APDERM]
      ,[IN HOUSE]
      ,[RAD EMR ORDERS]
      ,[EMR ORDERS]
  FROM [database].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
```

Which produces this:

[image]

How can I write a query which will add each column and insert a new row under the `[MYTABLE]`

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: If the Date is indeed a DateTime field - you won't be able to insert string "Total" into it. Also totals don't really belong in tables with data - that's for presentation layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` operator:

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[APDERM]
      ,[IN HOUSE]
      ,[RAD EMR ORDERS]
      ,[EMR ORDERS]
FROM [database].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
UNION
SELECT  [Date]
      , SUM([APDERM])
      , SUM([IN HOUSE])
      , SUM([RAD EMR ORDERS])
      , SUM([EMR ORDERS](
  FROM [database].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to write to a new table?

Comment: WITH cte AS (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...) SELECT * INTO #MyTable FROM cte;

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do EXACTLY what you asked for, but this should be close enough:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Date]
      ,[APDERM]
      ,[IN HOUSE]
      ,[RAD EMR ORDERS]
      ,[EMR ORDERS]
  FROM [database].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
COMPUTE SUM(APDERM), SUM([In House]), SUM([RAD EMR ORDERS]), SUM([EMR ORDERS])
```

This will post the sums of those columns as a second dataset, rather than appending it to the end of that one.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this to do it in a single statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Date]
      ,SUM([APDERM]) AS [APDERM]
      ,SUM([IN HOUSE]) AS [IN HOUSE]
      ,SUM([RAD EMR ORDERS]) AS [RAD EMR ORDERS]
      ,SUM([EMR ORDERS]) AS [EMR ORDERS]
FROM [database].[dbo].[MYTABLE]
GROUP BY [Date]
WITH ROLLUP
```